# What happens when you shift array elements outside the arrays range?

Tags: c, embedded

Say I've got an array that contains 100 elements. Same array only has elements 0 through 69 filled because that's all the data that was captured and 70 through 99 are zeros.

Before the data in the array is transferred, a start of message must be added to the beginning and has to be inserted after gathering the data.

To insert the data, you use a for loop to manually shift the array elements to the right by n (see the code below).

```c
uint8_t foo[100]; 

/*
 * Some code that puts data in the first 70 elements
 */ 

//Need to insert the start of message
for(i=99; i>0; i--)
{
    foo[i+1] = foo[i];
}
```

On the first run of that for loop, it makes foo[100] = foo[99]. Is that a valid operation or does foo[100] just go off into never never land? I know in languages like MATLAB, it will dynamically resize your array, but does C do the same thing?

Comment: C does not. ```foo[100]``` will go outside the buffer.

Comment: `foo[100]` is not a valid element of `foo`. It doesn't even go to "never never land", it may modify other variables, cause your program to crash, or introduce any behaviour. This is undefined behaviour. (See [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).)

Comment: You can't assume that elements 70-99 are zeros unless you explicitly assign them

Comment: Oh my god, Matlab users trying to code (looks familiar to what I see at work). How inefficient to shift everything .. why not keep a header part free, or use a separate header before switching to the array?

Answer (score 0):

C has no bounds checking and it doesn't automatically resize arrays. If you have a size 100 array, and you access index 100 (since arrays start at 0), then you're accessing the memory immediately outside the array's buffer.

*Best case scenario*, it seg faults. However, since the behavior is undefined, you may be overwriting other variables or doing all kinds of weird stuff.

Comment: Since it's not far outside of the array, it's pretty unlikely that you'd get a segfault from this.